# LibGDX - My splash screen isn't showing

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

Here is my splash screen:

```
package com.badlogic.gdx.screens;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class Splash implements Screen {

private SpriteBatch batch;
private Sprite splash;


@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1); //sets clear color to black
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); //clear the batch

    batch.begin();
    splash.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void show() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("badlogic.jpg"));
    splash = new Sprite(texture);
    splash.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}

}
```

When I run the application, the splash screen doesn't show, it just jumps straight to the game itself. I'm knew at this so I'm not completely sure what the problem is. My best guess is that the splash screen isn't linked to the game screen but I'm not sure.

Heres the Main Game screen, I don't have a menu yet.

```
public class SlingshotSteve extends Game {
   private OrthographicCamera camera;
   // Creates our 2D images
   private SpriteBatch batch;
   private TextureRegion backgroundTexture;
   private Texture texture;


@Override
public void create() {
    setScreen(new Splash());

    camera = new OrthographicCamera(1280, 720);

    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("background.jpg"));
    backgroundTexture = new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 0, 500, 500);

    Music mp3Sound = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("rain.mp3"));
    mp3Sound.setLooping(true);
    mp3Sound.play();



}


@Override
public void render() {  
    super.render();

      Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

      camera.update();
      batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

      batch.begin();
      batch.draw(backgroundTexture, 0, 0); 
      batch.end();

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    super.resize(width, height);

}

@Override
public void pause() {
    super.pause();

}

@Override
public void resume() {
    super.resume();

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
       batch.dispose();
       texture.dispose();
       super.dispose();

}
}
```

Comment: Show where you are actually setting the SplashScreen to be used.

Comment: Their, I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem lies here

```
@Override
public void render() {  
    super.render();

    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

     camera.update();
     batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

     batch.begin();
     batch.draw(backgroundTexture, 0, 0); 
     batch.end();
```

}

I believe that `super.render()` calls your current screen's render method, which means that your splash screen is indeed drawing itself. However, since right afterwards you draw your background, the actual splash screen is not visible.

Try commenting out everything but `super.render();` in your render method, and see if that doesn't fix things.

Comment: That works, but what I want is for the splash screen to show, then I want it to disappear and then the game screen starts. Since I'm commenting out everything in the render method, The splash screen just shows and nothing else. How can I do this?

Comment: @Dakota you would need another screen (`GameScreen` or something similar), who's render method would include most of the code you currently have in `Game`'s render you would then (after a delay or something), call `setScreen` on game to that screen, from inside your `Splash` Screen. Check out the [tutorial on screens](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Extending-the-simple-game) for more information

Answer (score 0):

It's because you provide an implementation for `render()` in your `Game` class, rather than use a separate `Screen`. If you use `Screen`s, you mustn't provide an implementation for `render()` in your `Game` class.

Also, you should allocate the `Texture` for the `SplashScreen` in a constructor, rather than in the `show()` method. But that's just a minor caveat.

Comment: Ok, but how do I achieve that? Could you please link a tutorial if possible?

Comment: You seriously just need to make a game screen class, implement the render function there, then from the splash screen when the splash timer ends, set the screen in Game to be the game screen